# Lectura de Excel gigante muy lenta con Python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Estoy intentando sacar de un documento Excel muy simple, ya que tiene una sola hoja y muy pocas columnas, pero muy largo ya que tiene casi 1 millon de filas, los datos de las celdas para escribir frases con ellos en un documento TXT.

Utilizo openpyxl para abrir el Excel, junto con los atributos de read-only y data-only a TRUE.

El código python es muy simple:

```
def Frase(wsSheet, txtFile):
    for r in range(2,wsSheet.max_row+1):
        anho= "20"+str(wsSheet.cell(row=r, column=3).value)
        nombre= str(wsSheet.cell(row=r, column=1).value)
        print("Nombre: "+nombre+", Año de nacimiento: "+anho+"\n")
        txtFile.write("Nombre: "+nombre+", Año de nacimiento: "+anho+"\n")
```

He probado a quitar tanto read-only como data-only para ver si aceleraba el proceso, pero si quito alguno de los dos atributos, no carga nada en absoluto, incluso pasados minutos, no reacciona. Con los 2 atributos, si que reacciona y comienza a escribir, pero llega un punto que cada vez va mas lento pasando de escribir mas de 20 por segundo aprox, a 2 o 3 por segundo, si echo cuentas me jubilo antes de que acabe...

Hay alguna manera de acelerar el proceso?

Gracias.

Comment: Suelo usar `pandas`. para leer los excel lo hago de esta manera: `df = pd.read_excel("directorio del archivo.xlsx")`. Puedes probar y controlar si tarda más

Comment: A priori me parece que leer 1 millon de filas es pesado y hay que entenderlo (cuanto bytes pesa el excel?). Ahora tal vez puedas optimizar ese for minimizando la cantidad de operaciones de I/O de disco. En particular el write sobre el textfile y la indexación de la celda puede ser caro, más aun dentro de un ciclo for. Ahora lo que haría sería tratar de proyectar dichas columnas y sus filas a una estructura intermedia y hacer el write sobre algun buffer, cosa de hacer las operaciones de disco fuera de ese for para evitar el sobre costo de transporte. Intentar otro parser como el de pandas tb.